# MinGW - Собрать бинарный файл для Linux из под Windows 7

Tags: c, компиляция, c++

У меня установлен под Windows 7 компилятор MinGW. Как я могу осуществить кросс компиляцию, т.е. собрать бинарный файл для Linux. Какие опции компилятора надо задать? И возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: А зачем нужно такое извращение, позвольте спросить? Поставьте в виртуальной машине линукс, сделайте общие папки и компилируйте на здоровье.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MinGW создан для прямо противоположной задачи, когда код собирается на Linux, а выполняется на Windows, поэтому маловероятно, что это вообще возможно. Как прямо сказано на [сайте](http://www.mingw.org/) MinGW

> tool set which is suitable for the development of **native MS-Windows** applications

Для кросс-компиляции с Windows на Linux нужен Cygwin.

Comment: ну вот я сейчас пытаюсь собрать компилятор нужной версии под Cygwin...целый день маюсь :(

Comment: Давайте расставим все точки над i. 
И Cygwin, и MinGW имеют одну цель - обеспечить возможность собрать и исполнить в Windows код, написанный для Unix, со всеми специфичными для юниксов системными вызовами, библиотечными функциями, расширениями компилятора и т.д. Т.е. для обеспечения совместимости на уровне кода программы, а не на бинарном уровне, чтобы программу, написанную для юникса можно было без переделки кода скомпилировать и запустить на винде. При этом создаются windows-бинарники.

Comment: вот я собрал кросс-компилятор под Linux'ом. В Linux он работает.. Я могу его запустить в Windows под Cywin ? или нет?

Comment: 1. Поподробней, пожалуйста: что за кросс-компилятор и т.д.
2. А почему бы самому не попробовать?

Comment: 1) компилятор gcc gcc-3.4.3-glibc-2.3.4 вот отсюда http://kegel.com/crosstool/crosstool-0.43/doc/crosstool-howto.html#quick
2) уже попробовал, не запускается, думал как-то иначе нужно это делать, но потом зашел на сайт Cygwin и прочитал там: Cygwin is not:

a way to run native Linux apps on Windows. You must rebuild your application from source if you want it to run on Windows.

Comment: Что и требовалось доказать